# How to install docx2pdf python module in msys2 (mingw - windows 64 bit)

Tags: python, pdf, docx, msys2

I am trying to install [docx2pdf module](https://pypi.org/project/docx2pdf/).

I think that has dependency pywin32.
I tried to install the last package in msys but i got this error:

```
Χρήστος@Chris-pc MINGW64 /c/python/scripts/Papinhio player/notes/pywin32-master
$ python setup.py build
Building pywin32 3.8.301.1
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.mingw-3.8
creating build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32
creating build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32/lib
copying win32\lib/afxres.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32\lib
copying win32\lib/commctrl.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32\lib
copying win32\lib/dbi.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32\lib
copying win32\lib/mmsystem.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32\lib
copying win32\lib/netbios.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32\lib
copying win32\lib/ntsecuritycon.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32\lib
copying win32\lib/pywin32_bootstrap.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32\lib
copying win32\lib/pywin32_testutil.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32\lib
copying win32\lib/pywintypes.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32\lib
copying win32\lib/rasutil.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32\lib
copying win32\lib/regcheck.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32\lib
copying win32\lib/regutil.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32\lib
copying win32\lib/sspi.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32\lib
copying win32\lib/sspicon.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32\lib
copying win32\lib/win32con.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32\lib
copying win32\lib/win32cryptcon.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32\lib
copying win32\lib/win32evtlogutil.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32\lib
copying win32\lib/win32gui_struct.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32\lib
copying win32\lib/win32inetcon.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32\lib
copying win32\lib/win32netcon.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32\lib
copying win32\lib/win32pdhquery.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32\lib
copying win32\lib/win32pdhutil.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32\lib
copying win32\lib/win32rcparser.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32\lib
copying win32\lib/win32serviceutil.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32\lib
copying win32\lib/win32timezone.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32\lib
copying win32\lib/win32traceutil.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32\lib
copying win32\lib/win32verstamp.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32\lib
copying win32\lib/winerror.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32\lib
copying win32\lib/winioctlcon.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32\lib
copying win32\lib/winnt.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32\lib
copying win32\lib/winperf.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32\lib
copying win32\lib/winxptheme.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32\lib
creating build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com
copying com/win32com/olectl.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com
copying com/win32com/storagecon.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com
copying com/win32com/universal.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com
copying com/win32com/util.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com
copying com/win32com/__init__.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com
creating build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/client
copying com/win32com/client/build.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/client
copying com/win32com/client/CLSIDToClass.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/clie
nt
copying com/win32com/client/combrowse.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/client
copying com/win32com/client/connect.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/client
copying com/win32com/client/dynamic.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/client
copying com/win32com/client/gencache.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/client
copying com/win32com/client/genpy.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/client
copying com/win32com/client/makepy.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/client
copying com/win32com/client/selecttlb.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/client
copying com/win32com/client/tlbrowse.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/client
copying com/win32com/client/util.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/client
copying com/win32com/client/__init__.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/client
creating build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/demos
copying com/win32com/demos/connect.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/demos
copying com/win32com/demos/dump_clipboard.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/dem
os
copying com/win32com/demos/eventsApartmentThreaded.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win
32com/demos
copying com/win32com/demos/eventsFreeThreaded.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com
/demos
copying com/win32com/demos/excelAddin.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/demos
copying com/win32com/demos/excelRTDServer.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/dem
os
copying com/win32com/demos/iebutton.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/demos
copying com/win32com/demos/ietoolbar.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/demos
copying com/win32com/demos/outlookAddin.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/demos
copying com/win32com/demos/trybag.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/demos
copying com/win32com/demos/__init__.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/demos
creating build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/makegw
copying com/win32com/makegw/makegw.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/makegw
copying com/win32com/makegw/makegwenum.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/makegw
copying com/win32com/makegw/makegwparse.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/makeg
w
copying com/win32com/makegw/__init__.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/makegw
creating build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/server
copying com/win32com/server/connect.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/server
copying com/win32com/server/dispatcher.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/server
copying com/win32com/server/exception.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/server
copying com/win32com/server/factory.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/server
copying com/win32com/server/localserver.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/serve
r
copying com/win32com/server/policy.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/server
copying com/win32com/server/register.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/server
copying com/win32com/server/util.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/server
copying com/win32com/server/__init__.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/server
creating build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/servers
copying com/win32com/servers/dictionary.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/serve
rs
copying com/win32com/servers/interp.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/servers
copying com/win32com/servers/perfmon.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/servers
copying com/win32com/servers/PythonTools.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/serv
ers
copying com/win32com/servers/test_pycomtest.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/s
ervers
copying com/win32com/servers/__init__.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/servers
creating build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/test
copying com/win32com/test/daodump.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/test
copying com/win32com/test/errorSemantics.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/test
copying com/win32com/test/GenTestScripts.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/test
copying com/win32com/test/pippo_server.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/test
copying com/win32com/test/policySemantics.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/tes
t
copying com/win32com/test/testAccess.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/test
copying com/win32com/test/testADOEvents.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/test
copying com/win32com/test/testall.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/test
copying com/win32com/test/testArrays.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/test
copying com/win32com/test/testAXScript.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/test
copying com/win32com/test/testClipboard.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/test
copying com/win32com/test/testCollections.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/tes
t
copying com/win32com/test/testConversionErrors.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32co
m/test
copying com/win32com/test/testDates.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/test
copying com/win32com/test/testDCOM.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/test
copying com/win32com/test/testDictionary.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/test
copying com/win32com/test/testDynamic.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/test
copying com/win32com/test/testExchange.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/test
copying com/win32com/test/testExplorer.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/test
copying com/win32com/test/testGatewayAddresses.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32co
m/test
copying com/win32com/test/testGIT.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/test
copying com/win32com/test/testIterators.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/test
copying com/win32com/test/testmakepy.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/test
copying com/win32com/test/testMarshal.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/test
copying com/win32com/test/testMSOffice.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/test
copying com/win32com/test/testMSOfficeEvents.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/
test
copying com/win32com/test/testNetscape.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/test
copying com/win32com/test/testPersist.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/test
copying com/win32com/test/testPippo.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/test
copying com/win32com/test/testPyComTest.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/test
copying com/win32com/test/testROT.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/test
copying com/win32com/test/testServers.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/test
copying com/win32com/test/testShell.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/test
copying com/win32com/test/testStorage.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/test
copying com/win32com/test/testStreams.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/test
copying com/win32com/test/testvb.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/test
copying com/win32com/test/testvbscript_regexp.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com
/test
copying com/win32com/test/testWMI.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/test
copying com/win32com/test/testxslt.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/test
copying com/win32com/test/util.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/test
copying com/win32com/test/__init__.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com/test
creating build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32comext
creating build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32comext/adsi
copying com/win32comext/adsi/adsicon.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32comext/adsi
copying com/win32comext/adsi/__init__.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32comext/adsi
creating build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32comext/axscript
copying com/win32comext/axscript/asputil.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32comext/a
xscript
copying com/win32comext/axscript/__init__.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32comext/
axscript
creating build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32comext/axscript/client
copying com/win32comext/axscript/client/debug.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com
ext/axscript/client
copying com/win32comext/axscript/client/error.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com
ext/axscript/client
copying com/win32comext/axscript/client/framework.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win3
2comext/axscript/client
copying com/win32comext/axscript/client/pydumper.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32
comext/axscript/client
copying com/win32comext/axscript/client/pyscript.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32
comext/axscript/client
copying com/win32comext/axscript/client/pyscript_rexec.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8
/win32comext/axscript/client
copying com/win32comext/axscript/client/scriptdispatch.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8
/win32comext/axscript/client
copying com/win32comext/axscript/client/__init__.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32
comext/axscript/client
creating build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32comext/axscript/server
copying com/win32comext/axscript/server/axsite.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32co
mext/axscript/server
copying com/win32comext/axscript/server/error.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com
ext/axscript/server
copying com/win32comext/axscript/server/__init__.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32
comext/axscript/server
creating build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32comext/axdebug
copying com/win32comext/axdebug/adb.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32comext/axdebu
g
copying com/win32comext/axdebug/codecontainer.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32com
ext/axdebug
copying com/win32comext/axdebug/contexts.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32comext/a
xdebug
copying com/win32comext/axdebug/debugger.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32comext/a
xdebug
copying com/win32comext/axdebug/documents.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32comext/
axdebug
copying com/win32comext/axdebug/dump.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32comext/axdeb
ug
copying com/win32comext/axdebug/expressions.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32comex
t/axdebug
copying com/win32comext/axdebug/gateways.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32comext/a
xdebug
copying com/win32comext/axdebug/stackframe.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32comext
/axdebug
copying com/win32comext/axdebug/util.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32comext/axdeb
ug
copying com/win32comext/axdebug/__init__.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32comext/a
xdebug
creating build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32comext/propsys
copying com/win32comext/propsys/pscon.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32comext/prop
sys
copying com/win32comext/propsys/__init__.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32comext/p
ropsys
creating build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32comext/shell
copying com/win32comext/shell/shellcon.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32comext/she
ll
copying com/win32comext/shell/__init__.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32comext/she
ll
creating build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32comext/mapi
copying com/win32comext/mapi/emsabtags.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32comext/map
i
copying com/win32comext/mapi/mapitags.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32comext/mapi
copying com/win32comext/mapi/mapiutil.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32comext/mapi
copying com/win32comext/mapi/__init__.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32comext/mapi
creating build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32comext/ifilter
copying com/win32comext/ifilter/ifiltercon.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32comext
/ifilter
copying com/win32comext/ifilter/__init__.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32comext/i
filter
creating build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32comext/internet
copying com/win32comext/internet/inetcon.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32comext/i
nternet
copying com/win32comext/internet/__init__.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32comext/
internet
creating build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32comext/axcontrol
copying com/win32comext/axcontrol/__init__.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32comext
/axcontrol
creating build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32comext/taskscheduler
copying com/win32comext/taskscheduler/__init__.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32co
mext/taskscheduler
creating build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32comext/directsound
copying com/win32comext/directsound/__init__.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32come
xt/directsound
creating build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32comext/directsound/test
copying com/win32comext/directsound/test/ds_record.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win
32comext/directsound/test
copying com/win32comext/directsound/test/ds_test.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32
comext/directsound/test
copying com/win32comext/directsound/test/__init__.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win3
2comext/directsound/test
creating build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32comext/authorization
copying com/win32comext/authorization/__init__.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32co
mext/authorization
creating build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32comext/bits
copying com/win32comext/bits/__init__.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/win32comext/bits
creating build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin
creating build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin/pywin
copying pythonwin/pywin/__init__.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin/pywin
creating build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin/pywin/debugger
copying pythonwin/pywin/debugger/configui.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin/py
win/debugger
copying pythonwin/pywin/debugger/dbgcon.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin/pywi
n/debugger
copying pythonwin/pywin/debugger/dbgpyapp.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin/py
win/debugger
copying pythonwin/pywin/debugger/debugger.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin/py
win/debugger
copying pythonwin/pywin/debugger/fail.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin/pywin/
debugger
copying pythonwin/pywin/debugger/__init__.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin/py
win/debugger
creating build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin/pywin/dialogs
copying pythonwin/pywin/dialogs/ideoptions.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin/p
ywin/dialogs
copying pythonwin/pywin/dialogs/list.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin/pywin/d
ialogs
copying pythonwin/pywin/dialogs/login.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin/pywin/
dialogs
copying pythonwin/pywin/dialogs/status.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin/pywin
/dialogs
copying pythonwin/pywin/dialogs/__init__.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin/pyw
in/dialogs
creating build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin/pywin/docking
copying pythonwin/pywin/docking/DockingBar.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin/p
ywin/docking
copying pythonwin/pywin/docking/__init__.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin/pyw
in/docking
creating build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin/pywin/framework
copying pythonwin/pywin/framework/app.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin/pywin/
framework
copying pythonwin/pywin/framework/bitmap.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin/pyw
in/framework
copying pythonwin/pywin/framework/cmdline.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin/py
win/framework
copying pythonwin/pywin/framework/dbgcommands.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwi
n/pywin/framework
copying pythonwin/pywin/framework/dlgappcore.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin
/pywin/framework
copying pythonwin/pywin/framework/help.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin/pywin
/framework
copying pythonwin/pywin/framework/interact.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin/p
ywin/framework
copying pythonwin/pywin/framework/intpyapp.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin/p
ywin/framework
copying pythonwin/pywin/framework/intpydde.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin/p
ywin/framework
copying pythonwin/pywin/framework/mdi_pychecker.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/python
win/pywin/framework
copying pythonwin/pywin/framework/scriptutils.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwi
n/pywin/framework
copying pythonwin/pywin/framework/sgrepmdi.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin/p
ywin/framework
copying pythonwin/pywin/framework/startup.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin/py
win/framework
copying pythonwin/pywin/framework/stdin.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin/pywi
n/framework
copying pythonwin/pywin/framework/toolmenu.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin/p
ywin/framework
copying pythonwin/pywin/framework/window.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin/pyw
in/framework
copying pythonwin/pywin/framework/winout.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin/pyw
in/framework
copying pythonwin/pywin/framework/__init__.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin/p
ywin/framework
creating build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin/pywin/framework/editor
copying pythonwin/pywin/framework/editor/configui.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/pyth
onwin/pywin/framework/editor
copying pythonwin/pywin/framework/editor/document.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/pyth
onwin/pywin/framework/editor
copying pythonwin/pywin/framework/editor/editor.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/python
win/pywin/framework/editor
copying pythonwin/pywin/framework/editor/frame.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonw
in/pywin/framework/editor
copying pythonwin/pywin/framework/editor/ModuleBrowser.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8
/pythonwin/pywin/framework/editor
copying pythonwin/pywin/framework/editor/template.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/pyth
onwin/pywin/framework/editor
copying pythonwin/pywin/framework/editor/vss.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin
/pywin/framework/editor
copying pythonwin/pywin/framework/editor/__init__.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/pyth
onwin/pywin/framework/editor
creating build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin/pywin/framework/editor/color
copying pythonwin/pywin/framework/editor/color/coloreditor.py -> build/lib.mingw
-3.8/pythonwin/pywin/framework/editor/color
copying pythonwin/pywin/framework/editor/color/__init__.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.
8/pythonwin/pywin/framework/editor/color
creating build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin/pywin/idle
copying pythonwin/pywin/idle/AutoExpand.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin/pywi
n/idle
copying pythonwin/pywin/idle/AutoIndent.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin/pywi
n/idle
copying pythonwin/pywin/idle/CallTips.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin/pywin/
idle
copying pythonwin/pywin/idle/FormatParagraph.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin
/pywin/idle
copying pythonwin/pywin/idle/IdleHistory.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin/pyw
in/idle
copying pythonwin/pywin/idle/PyParse.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin/pywin/i
dle
copying pythonwin/pywin/idle/__init__.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin/pywin/
idle
creating build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin/pywin/mfc
copying pythonwin/pywin/mfc/activex.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin/pywin/mf
c
copying pythonwin/pywin/mfc/afxres.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin/pywin/mfc
copying pythonwin/pywin/mfc/dialog.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin/pywin/mfc
copying pythonwin/pywin/mfc/docview.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin/pywin/mf
c
copying pythonwin/pywin/mfc/object.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin/pywin/mfc
copying pythonwin/pywin/mfc/thread.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin/pywin/mfc
copying pythonwin/pywin/mfc/window.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin/pywin/mfc
copying pythonwin/pywin/mfc/__init__.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin/pywin/m
fc
creating build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin/pywin/scintilla
copying pythonwin/pywin/scintilla/bindings.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin/p
ywin/scintilla
copying pythonwin/pywin/scintilla/config.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin/pyw
in/scintilla
copying pythonwin/pywin/scintilla/configui.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin/p
ywin/scintilla
copying pythonwin/pywin/scintilla/control.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin/py
win/scintilla
copying pythonwin/pywin/scintilla/document.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin/p
ywin/scintilla
copying pythonwin/pywin/scintilla/find.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin/pywin
/scintilla
copying pythonwin/pywin/scintilla/formatter.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin/
pywin/scintilla
copying pythonwin/pywin/scintilla/IDLEenvironment.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/pyth
onwin/pywin/scintilla
copying pythonwin/pywin/scintilla/keycodes.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin/p
ywin/scintilla
copying pythonwin/pywin/scintilla/scintillacon.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonw
in/pywin/scintilla
copying pythonwin/pywin/scintilla/view.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin/pywin
/scintilla
copying pythonwin/pywin/scintilla/__init__.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin/p
ywin/scintilla
creating build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin/pywin/tools
copying pythonwin/pywin/tools/browseProjects.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin
/pywin/tools
copying pythonwin/pywin/tools/browser.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin/pywin/
tools
copying pythonwin/pywin/tools/hierlist.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin/pywin
/tools
copying pythonwin/pywin/tools/regedit.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin/pywin/
tools
copying pythonwin/pywin/tools/regpy.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin/pywin/to
ols
copying pythonwin/pywin/tools/TraceCollector.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin
/pywin/tools
copying pythonwin/pywin/tools/__init__.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/pythonwin/pywin
/tools
creating build/lib.mingw-3.8/isapi
copying isapi/install.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/isapi
copying isapi/isapicon.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/isapi
copying isapi/simple.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/isapi
copying isapi/threaded_extension.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/isapi
copying isapi/__init__.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/isapi
creating build/lib.mingw-3.8/adodbapi
copying adodbapi/adodbapi.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/adodbapi
copying adodbapi/ado_consts.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/adodbapi
copying adodbapi/apibase.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/adodbapi
copying adodbapi/is64bit.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/adodbapi
copying adodbapi/process_connect_string.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/adodbapi
copying adodbapi/remote.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/adodbapi
copying adodbapi/schema_table.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/adodbapi
copying adodbapi/setup.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/adodbapi
copying adodbapi/__init__.py -> build/lib.mingw-3.8/adodbapi
running build_ext
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 2286, in 
    dist = setup(name="pywin32",
  File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", l
ine 153, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.8/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_com
mands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_com
mand
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "setup.py", line 505, in run
    build.run(self)
  File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.8/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, i
n run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.8/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_comm
and
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_com
mand
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.8/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 34
1, in run
    self.build_extensions()
  File "setup.py", line 807, in build_extensions
    self.compiler.initialize()
  File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.8/distutils/msvccompiler.py", line 259, in
 initialize
    self.__paths = self.get_msvc_paths("path")
  File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.8/distutils/msvccompiler.py", line 602, in
 get_msvc_paths
    r"\Win32 (%s)\Directories" % (self.__root, platform))
AttributeError: 'my_compiler' object has no attribute '_MSVCCompiler__root'
```

```
$ python -m pip install docx2pdf
Collecting docx2pdf
  Using cached docx2pdf-0.1.7-py3-none-any.whl (6.6 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm=4.41.0 in c:/msys64/mingw64/lib/pyth
on3.8/site-packages/tqdm-4.60.0-py3.8.egg (from docx2pdf) (4.60.0)
  Using cached docx2pdf-0.1.6-py3-none-any.whl (6.6 kB)
  Using cached docx2pdf-0.1.5-py3-none-any.whl (5.7 kB)
  Using cached docx2pdf-0.1.4-py3-none-any.whl (5.6 kB)
  Using cached docx2pdf-0.1.3-py3-none-any.whl (5.6 kB)
  Using cached docx2pdf-0.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (5.5 kB)
  Using cached docx2pdf-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (4.7 kB)
ERROR: Cannot install docx2pdf==0.1.0, docx2pdf==0.1.1, docx2pdf==0.1.3, docx2pd
f==0.1.4, docx2pdf==0.1.5, docx2pdf==0.1.6 and docx2pdf==0.1.7 because these pac
kage versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    docx2pdf 0.1.7 depends on pywin32=227; sys_platform == "win32"
    docx2pdf 0.1.6 depends on pywin32=227; sys_platform == "win32"
    docx2pdf 0.1.5 depends on pywin32=227; sys_platform == "win32"
    docx2pdf 0.1.4 depends on pywin32=227; sys_platform == "win32"
    docx2pdf 0.1.3 depends on pywin32=227; sys_platform == "win32"
    docx2pdf 0.1.1 depends on pywin32=227; sys_platform == "win32"
    docx2pdf 0.1.0 depends on pywin32=227; sys_platform == "win32"

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_g
uide/#fixing-conflicting-dependencies
```

Comment: Why do you need to use mingw instead of windows CMD/powershell?

Comment: I can't install python libshout module in windows enviroment. But i sucessfully installed in MSYS2 enviroment.

Comment: Okay, but according to the output shown, `depends on pywin32` means you'll probably need to be installing `docx2pdf` in a windows environment, not a bash shell. As the documentation says, only windows and Mac are supported, not mentioning Linux-like environments https://pypi.org/project/docx2pdf/, plus the error you posted in the deleted answer... `Can't find the Windows SDK` is self explanatory

Comment: You should probably be searching for the original error `AttributeError: 'my_compiler' object has no attribute '_MSVCCompiler__root'`, which might be related to needing Visual C++ libraries, although I'm not sure how you'd install those in MSYS2

Comment: @OneCricketeer it's not a big deal. For now i just use `python-docx` module which works fine in msys.

Comment: According to this: https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/issues/751#issuecomment-962662960 now pywin module is available in msys platform.